# Can we make DotfuscatorAttribute Invisible in Object Browser

Tags: c#

We are Developing a .NET DLL using Visual Studio 2015 . We would like to do dotfuscation using Dotfuscator Proffesional Edition 4.31.0 . After dotfuscation we see DotfuscatorAttribute that is visible in the Object Browser of  Visual Studio 2015. 
Is there any way to hide the DotfuscatorAttribute in the Object Browser?
Below is the Screen shot

[image: dotfuscatorattribute in object browser]

Comment: Why would you care. Your users won't see this and the ones that do won't be stopped by you trying to hide some stuff. What is your experience with obfuscation?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but this is our customer requirement. Is it possible to make dotfuscatorAttribute Invisible.

Comment: There is a way to mark things as hidden from VS's object browser: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/09/06/mark-methods-and-types-as-hidden-from-intellisense-and-the-object-browser/
I haven't really needed to hide attributes tho and thus not really sure this works in your case.

Comment: Maybe this? StripAfterObfuscation. 'Dotfuscator will always strip all attribute usages from an input assembly, regardless of this property, '

Comment: https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/references_attributes_obfuscation.html

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: use the `nodotfuscatorattribute` global option in the config file.

See [the manual](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/references_config_file.html#pctoc-nodotfuscatorattribute-option):

> #### NoDotfuscatorAttribute Option
>
> Dotfuscator, by default, inserts a custom attribute into your application named DotfuscatorAttribute. The
>   attribute contains information about the Dotfuscator version used to
>   obfuscate the program, including product ID (Community vs.
>   Professional) and version numbers. The purpose is threefold:
>
> - To identify which Dotfuscator version was used on a program.
> - Future Dotfuscator versions will use this information to identify already obfuscated third-party assemblies used as inputs, as special
>     treatment may be required in these cases.
> - PreEmptive Solutions is actively working with other tool vendors to ease the pain of debugging obfuscated code; the attribute helps those
>     tools know what they are dealing with.
>
> If these things are not as important to you as the increased security
>   of an anonymously obfuscated program, or if size reduction is a higher
>   priority, then you can disable insertion of the attribute by manually
>   setting an option in the config file, called nodotfuscatorattribute.
>
> NoDotfuscatorAttribute Option:
>
> ```
> <global>
>    <option>nodotfuscatorattribute</option>
> </global>
> ```